# Change style of GeoJSON features in Leaflet after it is done loading

Tags: geojson, style

Using Leaflet.js, I am loading a GeoJSON (containing many polygons) with the AJAX plugin (https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax), to which I pass a styling function. However, I would like to reapply colours to each feature after the whole GeoJSON is done loading. For this, I use a poly.on('data:loaded', function() {}, but I can't figure out how to make it work in Leaflet. Here's my code, how can I restyle my features after there are done loading?

```
function getColor(d) {
    return parseFloat(d) > 150000 ? '#800026' :
            parseFloat(d) < 150000  ? '#BD0026';
}

function style(feature) {
    return {
        weight: .5,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        fillColor: 'white')
    };
}

function style2(feature) {
    return {
        weight: .5,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties['var'])
    };
}

var poly = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('polygons.geojson', {style: style});
    poly.addTo(map);

poly.on('data:loaded', function() {
    poly.resetStyle(style2);
})
```

Comment: Have you tried using `setStyle` instead of `resetStyle`?